# How to make JpaRepository return records for repository specified class only?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, groovy, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
class A 

@Entity
class B extends A
```

and a spring JpaRepository interface:

```
@Repository
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<A>{
    @Query(value = "SELECT a FROM A AS a")
    List<A> find10(Pageable pageRequest)
}
```

When I call

`find10(new PageRequest(0, 10, new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, 'name'))`

from a service - it returns a list contains both `A` and `B` records. Similar to:

```
[B.class, B.class, A.class, B.class, A.class]
```

When I query `ARepository` I would like for only `A` records to be returned and the same respectively for `B` and `BRepository`.

**Does spring-jpa have a way for this to happen**? I'm using a version of Hibernate that has a bug where `@DiscriminatorColumn` does not work with `TABLE_PER_CLASS` and I **cannot** upgrade - so that is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create repository for B.class:

```
interface BRepository extends JpaRepository<B, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<B> {
...
```

This should work.

When you use `ARepostiory` hibernate will create **polimorphic query** that selects all entities that are `instanceof A`.

When your use `BRepository` hibernate will create concrete class query.

EDIT:

EDIT:

Maybe you should add new property to class hierarchy:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
class A {

    public String getType() {
        return "A";
    }
}

@Entity
class B extends A {

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "B";
    }
}
```

This will introduce new column `type` to table definition. And hibernate will set "A" for `A.class` and "B" for `B.class`. You can change type from String to Enum to have stronger JPA query.

Comment: I do have a repository for B as well.. and while querying BRepository, I only get B records. But it is not the same for ARepository - I am still getting A and B records.

Comment: I need ARepository to only return concrete A records.

Comment: Your edit is a solution that I considered - but then I would have to navigate through hundreds of queries in the project modifying them to search with the type criteria. I was hoping for a more automatic solution.